Use of genitive in negation
I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly the rule is on the use of the genitive case after negation.
One could say
"читаю эту книгу", and the negative would be "не читаю эту книгу", as "эту книгу" is still the indirect object.
However, when it comes to понять, for example, it's:
"понимаю это" - "не понимаю этого".
At first I thought it could have the idea translated as something like "I understand that" - "I don't understand of that", but I found out that "*понимаю этого" is incorrect.
Can anyone explain what exactly the rule is, and how the logic behind it works?

"as "эту книгу" is still the indirect object": Did you mean the direct object?


Can anyone explain what exactly is the rule, how does the logic behind it work?

The rule is that when you have a verb that accepts a complement (direct object) in the accusative in affirmative sentences, this verb can accept both the accusative and the genitive in negative sentences. The accusative is preferred when the object is definite (i.e. you would have used the article "the" with the object in the corresponding English phrase).
Some verbs can accept the direct object in the genitive as well, in which case it serves as the partitive case: налить чай/чаю, насыпать сахар/сахару etc.
As for the logic behind it, I honestly don't know.
The most direct (and useless) answer is that it works that way in Russian.
A slightly less direct, and probably equally useless answer is that some believe that Russian borrowed it from some of its Uralic neighbors (by which its grammar had been heavily influenced). It, apparently, works the same way in Finnish. I don't speak any Finnish, but DeepL gives me näen linnun and minä en näe lintua for "I see a bird" and "I don't see a bird", the word for "bird" being used in the accusative and the partitive, respectively. This just raises the question of why it works this way in Finnish, to which I don't know the answer either.
If I were to hypothesize, I would say that this distinction is there to fill some gap for a grammatical feature that was present in the substrate language of the pre-Uralic population that Uralic speakers have absorbed, and for whom Uralic languages were second languages.
This kind of thing happens often in many languages around the world: articles in Bulgarian and Romance languages, complex pronoun systems in the English-based creoles of Oceania, periphrastic "do" in English (a Celtic influence, according to some linguists), etc.
But that's just a wild hypothesis that come a dime a dozen, and we don't really have any means to check it.

This is a hardy perennial as an issue. If you look at https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_Comprehensive_Russian_Grammar/_hYYPmyosHQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=genitive+after+negation&pg=PA112&printsec=frontcover - this is the book we used at university - you will see that both are found, but the genitive is more likely with indefinite and the accusative more likely with definite uses. But on top of that, the use of the genitive after negation is receding in Russian, although that textbook doesn't discuss that. Maybe a native speaker will comment on that.
Examples given there: я не вижу стола, I can't see any table. я не вижу стол, I can't see the table. (The fact Russian doesn't have articles means that definiteness is still conveyed in other ways.)
He adds that where there are compound negatives, the genitive is advisable: он никогда и никому не говорил непрадвы.
Also with один: он не прочитал ни одной книги.
And with the gerund: не скрывая своей радости.
And with abstract nouns: не иметь понятия.
And with это, as you already know.
A lot of other considerations are mentioned there, including the fact that with a person, eg свою сестру, the accusative is more likely after a negative, but you need to read the whole section of the book, three or four pages.
